# Directory is not created inside virtual environment folder

Tags: django

I am creating a django project but when I create a directory it is not created inside my current directory.
I first installed virtualenv and after that I created a virtual environment by virtualenv env_mysite.

Then I activated it by env_mysite\scripts\activate. Then I installed django by pip install django==1.11.2 . After that I tested and django was installed successfully.

I activated the environment again and tried to create a directory by typing "django-admin startproject mysite". However the mysite directory was created inside Users\reza but not inside env_mysite folder. Could you please explain what is wrong here? why directory is not created inside env_mysite which is my virtual environment?

Thank you

Comment: The project is supposed to be created at the path your terminal currently points to. So if you open a terminal in `Users\reza`, it will create the project there. If you want to create it somewhere else, `cd` to the directory and then run the command.

Comment: Note however it makes no difference where the directory is created - there's no need for it to be within the virtualenv.